# ExtJS 6 Modern сolor field change event doesnt work

Tags: extjs, extjs6

ExtJS 6 modern toolkit `colorfield` [change](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.ux.colorpick.Field.html#event-change) doesnt fire when I select color using picker - check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vuv).

Am I not using this event correctly or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in sencha.
To make it work you can override the `colorfield` like:

```
Ext.define("SomeColorField", {
    override: "Ext.ux.colorpick.Field",
    onColorPickerOK: function (colorPicker) {
        var oldValue = this.getValue();
        this.setColor(colorPicker.getColor());
        this.updateValue(colorPicker.getColor());
        this.collapse();
        this.fireEvent('change', this, this.getValue(), oldValue);
   }
});
```

Example on https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/301v